# Is this theory for refuting the second law of thermodynamics logically valid and sound?

Tags: logic

The second law of thermodynamics essentially argues that "usable energy is irretrievably lost in the form of unusable energy".

However, we can refute this, primarily because of the universe we exist in:

In order for this universe to exist, energy has to exist, but in order for the initial occurrant state of energy to exist, more energy has to exist (energy cannot appear from nowhere, reportedly).

This repeats on up until you have infinite energy, refuting the original claim of the second law of thermodynamics.

Or, to boil it down, it argues 'usable energy can't appear out of thin air'. The existence of the very statement saying that is a contradiction to that very statement.

Is this a valid and sound refutation?

Comment: It seems more like a refutation of the Big Bang Theory than a refutation of the second law. You're arguing that energy can't exist without more energy to create it...but what if, at some point, there just "was" energy, with no causality to explain it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a physics question.

Comment: This is a physics question, not a logic or philosophy question. Please migrate it to the appropriate SE.

Comment: I would not migrate it seeing as there is already two questions on it here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214667/why-is-the-second-law-of-thermodynamics-undisputableand here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91017/why-are-the-laws-of-thermodynamics-supreme-among-the-laws-of-nature

Comment: I only know this because I asked one of them three hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

First off, given how well accepted the laws of thermodynamics are, you should really rephrase the title from "is this valid" to "how is this not valid," because you should expect to get it crushed.  Utterly crushed.  You are literally trying to refute something which has been studied for millions upon millions of hours, and entire industries are built on it.

Consider this very simple counter example, from the age of Zeno.  I start with a universe with a finite amount of energy.  Every operation halves the amount of energy in the system.  Can I ever run out of energy?  I certainly never had infinite energy, so your refutation does not apply there, and yet the second law of thermodynamics held.

If you want more than just a refutation from 400BC, you may need to formalize your refutation into proper mathematical language.  Zeno's paradox got handled nicely by the concept of limits when we began to accept calculus as valid.  There's also a lot of set theory you may want to explore if you want to start doing infinite recursions that are not well defined in calculus terms.

There's some interesting questions you may elect to ask as you start grasping the mathematics of the big bang.  Some of the questions don't even have strong answers.  However, "refuting" thermodynamics is not an easy task.

As a freebie: the laws of thermodynamics only apply to thermodynamic systems.  If you ever think you have refuted them, you'll find they simply don't apply to the system you describe.  Granted there's a lot of belief that they *do* apply, and lots of mathematical modeling on that.  But refuting their belief is not the same as refuting thermodynamics.

Comment: You have accepted his error as to the proper meaning of the law itself.  Even though these are good arguments, he is wrong at a much more basic level.

Comment: @jobermark I targeted a wording which would assist the OP in challenging his own position

Answer (score 2):

No, your refutation is absolutely not sound and valid.

But just for the sake of perversity, I will argue that it is, probably by accident, not necessarily invalid.

The second law of thermodynamics holds for any and all "closed" systems and can be reversed locally, as with a refrigerator, by importing energy.

As far as I know, we have no way to adequately define the state of "the universe" in these terms. And it is not as if the "big bang" or "dark energy" are comfortably understood.

So while your question is by no means a refutation of a fundamental law of physics, it does perhaps expose the overreach of today's cosmological and highly speculative theories.

Don't wait up for a call from the Nobel committee.

Answer (score 0):

What you cite is not the second law of thermodynamics. It is a vague corollary that introduces the undefinable word 'usable'.

The law is 'Entropy increases with time" meaning the sub-states of a system become more evenly distributed and not more clustered statistically. There is no reason some use cannot ultimately be contrived for the random lack of contrast that will ultimately result.  Much of the entropic heat on Earth maintains the temperature, which keeps my blood from solidifying.  And I use it for that.

It does not take 'plentiful useful energy' to characterize the initial state away from which all time flows, but rather 'extreme order with little variation'.  Your argument holds no sway over the latter, accurate description of what the second law actually predicts.

You have, in effect, disproven your own deduction of the corollary from the original by changing the meaning of the undefinable word.

Comment: The OP uses the phrase "usable energy" which is a well known wording to describe energy which can be used by a thermodynamic process to do work.  I see that phrasing all the time to indicate exactly what the OP means.  As for your example, the entropic heat on the Earth is only usable thermodynamically because there is a cooler body out there (the deep of space), so you can do thermodynamic work using the heat of the Earth.

Comment: @CortAmmon  I have changed to match the wording bit it is still not well-defined.  It depends upon the environment.  It is hard to picture the regularity of extreme low entropy as usable energy.  And the framing that creates that difficulty is still his main problem.